# Going to Bogus StackExchange subdomain results in Yellow Screen of Death

Tags: support, bug, status-completed

Currently, going to a bogus StackExchange site results in a YSOD. For example:

http://foo.stackexchange.com/

Gives the typical "Runtime Error".

If I recall correctly, it use to take you to https://stackexchange.com/ if the site didn't exist.

Comment: That screen is not nearly as scary or deadly looking as BSOD.

Comment: http://casperOne.stackexchange.com doesn't work.  This is *obviously* wrong.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We just deployed a fix. Thanks for the report.

Comment: +1 for the use of a panda on that page. <3

Comment: Well, I didn't recall correctly (I remember the panda now), but thanks for addressing it.